# using ng-options with angular to display select option with key and value and setting a default value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I have the following json:

```
[
    {"country": "United States", "code": "US"},
    {"country": "Canada", "code": "CA"},
    {"country": "Mexico", "code": "MX"}
 ]
```

In my view i have

```
 <select ng-model="selectedCountry" name="selectedCountry" id="selectedCountry" ng-options="country.country as country.country for country in countries" ng-change="onCountryChange()" required></select>
```

i am able to set a default country in my controller but the only problem is the drop down looks like this

```
 <option value="0" selected="selected">United States</option>
 <option value="1">Canada</option>
 <option value="2">Mexico</option>
```

when i add track by country.code in my ng-options i get the select list correctly with values set correctly

```
 <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
 <option value="US">United States</option> 
 <option value="CA">Canada</option>
 <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
```

but i am unable to set a default from my controller

```
 $scope.selectedCountry = "Canada";
```

or

```
    $scope.selectedCountry = "CA";
```

Does anyone know how i can fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `track by` expression, you can omit any other properties and set the default value like this:

```
$scope.selectedCountry = { code: "CA" };
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** If you would like the value of `$scope.selectedCountry` to be just a string (i.e. 'US', 'CA, or 'MX'), there is no need to use `track by`, you could use an `ng-options` like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCountry" name="selectedCountry" id="selectedCountry" ng-options="country.code as country.country for country in countries" ng-change="onCountryChange()" required></select>
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/QBRoV09sAlufSffpPPpJ?p=preview

Comment: This seems to work but i notice that when i change the country from the default it creates a <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>

Comment: That is because your `ng-options` expression isn't complatible with the track by. What is the expected value that you want the `$scope.selectedCountry` to be?

Comment: I want it to be US or CA or MX